# c++ templates and const (violation without compiler warning using auto)

Tags: c++, c++11

Code:

```
#include "utils/LinkedList.h"
#include "utils/RefCount.h"
#include <iostream>

#include "utils/testobject.h"

int Object::nextId = 0;

int main(void) {
    ::Utils::LinkedList<::Utils::RefCountedPtr<Object>> list;
    list.append(new Object());

    auto reference = list[0];

    const auto other = list[0];
    //both IDE and GCC see below line as error:
    //with: error: passing ‘const Object’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void Object::setThing(int)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
    //other->setThing(3);
    auto test = other;
    //this is fine - IT SHOULD NOT BE
    test->setThing(5);
    ::std::cout<<"Id: "<<other->getId()<<"\n";
}
```

There are no warnings generated, there is a constructor for the ref counted pointer that takes a const ref counted ptr (copy constructor) - the ref count is mutable. Still I'd expect a warning.

(As you can't have const constructors I'd assumed that a const declaration was a normal copy followed by treating the result as const - still I'd expect a warning)

These are my first steps venturing out using auto (I usually use auto complete) and no naked pointers, I would use the standard library ones but this is more of an exercise if anything, I want to get used to using traits and the other type utilities

**Expected:**
auto worked, it correctly gets (I mouse over in my IDE and the fact stuff works confirms the compiler is doing what I expect) on the first two, that's to say `reference` and `other` work fine.

It doesn't (and nor does my IDE) get `test` right, that is it discards the `const` and (as you can see) I can use "setThing" which I should not be able to do.

**Addendum**

Copy constructor:

```
RefCountedPtr(const RefCountedPtr& from) {
    refCount = from.refCount;
    (*refCount)++;
    data = from.data;
}
```

Comment: What is your question? You do not have a SSCCE example.

Comment: It sounds to me like your IDE is wrong and your compiler is right.

Comment: @juanchopanza neither generate a warning for the `auto test=other;` line but both recognise that `other` is const, yet `test` isn't.

Comment: Right, there shouldn't be a warning, and `test` shouldn't be `const`.

Comment: @juanchopanza in that case, how can I make it so test is const? (I cannot have a `const constructor` obviously)

Comment: Did you intend to use `::Utils::RefCountedPtr<const Object>`?

Comment: @sth I think I'm going to have to, but that's a separate topic. I did expect compiler warnings though because I assign a `T*` member of a const object to a `T*` of a non-const object. I'd like such a warning...

Comment: @AlecTeal I would just say `const auto test = other;`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I'd like a solution that warned me if I forgot that const. Sorry to be pushy but here I have "accidentally" discarded const, that scares me.

Comment: That is going to be tough, because you aren't discarding `const`. You are making a copy of an object. The copy does not have to know anything about whether the original was `const` or not. Saying `const int n = 42; int m = n;` is perfectly fine.

Comment: @juanchopanza I've added the copy-ctor to the end, I'd have expected a warning on the `data=from.data` line. I really am quite shocked it let me do that.

Comment: @AlecTeal: `data=from.data` creates a copy of the (const) `from.data`. That's perfectly fine. `from.data` won't get modifed. (Presumably you are copying a `Object *const` to a new `Object*` there. Note that the pointer itself is `const`, not the pointed-to Object. You can modify the `Object` through both these pointers.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say

```
auto test = other;
```

you create a non-`const` copy of `other`. Clearly, there is no issue creating a copy from a `const` object nor is there a restriction on functions being called on non-`const` objects. If you wanted to create reference, you'd have written

```
auto&& test = other;
```

which would keep the `const` qualification, obviously.

Comment: ` RefCountedPtr(const RefCountedPtr& from) {
  refCount = from.refCount;
  (*refCount)++;
  data = from.data;
 }` I would expect a warning from this, (that I am discarding the `data`'s constness), can I create a `const constructor` or a way to cast to a `const Object` as a template param for the ref counting pointer?

Comment: Copy assignment has no problem assigning a `const` object to a non-`const` object either. ... and since you object seems to be a pointer, not that the `const` qualification on the containing object affects the `const`ness of the pointer, not the pointee.

Comment: Why `auto&&`? Isn't `auto&` enough?

Comment: @BЈовић: well, I knew that `auto&&` would correctly deduce the `const`ness of the reference. I think `auto&` would work, too, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: I just suddenly got what auto does and what was happening, I feel really silly but I can't delete the question as you answered :P